# Is there an gcloud auth application-default print-access-token equivalent in C#?

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-vision, google-cloud-automl

I am currently working on a .net web app that uses GCP's automl vision model service which I query using RestSharp, the problem is that after some time I start getting Unauthorized responses from the model, I currently fix this by running

```
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

In a CMD and copying and pasting the token manually in the request like so:

```
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + "I paste it here" );
request.AddJsonBody(new {
    payload = new {
                   image = new
                   {
                        imageBytes = base64
                   }
            }
     });
```

Is there any way to do this automatically in C#?
If not, what's the correct approach to authenticating in this model?

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better placed using Google's auth library for .NET to manage the OAuth flow and use of credentials programmatically. You can then drop back to making REST calls against the API.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-csharp

***Suggestion**: create a service account (with appropriate permissions) and use that for auth instead of your user account as you're doing.*

It's unfortunate that Google does not appear to provide a Cloud Client Library(/-ies) for AuthML for .NET. You should pester Google Engineering to do this by filing an issue on [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to bypass this by using this [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BPC.GoogleAutoMLVision#)

It is as simple as using this code in case anyone needs it in the future:

```
GoogleAutoMLVisionClient automlClient = new GoogleAutoMLVisionClient("<My credentials.json>");
ICollection<PredictResult> automlResponses = automlClient.Predict("My endpoint:predict", file.OpenReadStream()).Result.payload;
foreach(PredictResult automlResult in automlResponses)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + automlResult.displayName + "Score:" + automlResult.classification.score.ToString());
}
```