# Fail to authorise a GCP Vertex call from .net core

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

With Google recent announcement of Vertex AI, I am now trying to call an endpoint I created. As I'm using c# (.net Core consol app), the only way I could find is using the REST API:

[https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/locations/us-central1/endpoints/${ENDPOINT_ID}:predict](https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1alpha1/projects/$%7BPROJECT_ID%7D/locations/us-central1/endpoints/$%7BENDPOINT_ID%7D:predict)

My code is using an API Key I created on GCP that is restricted to Vertex AI API.

The sVertexSearchPrm var is holding the following JSON:

```html
{
  "instances": [{
    "content": "YOUR_IMAGE_BYTES"
  }],
  "parameters": {
    "confidenceThreshold": 0.5,
    "maxPredictions": 5
  }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
            HttpClient client = Method_Headers(sVertexAPIKey, sVertexURI);
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, 
            Uri.EscapeUriString(client.BaseAddress.ToString()));
            request.Content = new StringContent(sVertexSearchPrm, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await 
            
            client.PostAsync(Uri.EscapeUriString(client.BaseAddress.ToString()), request.Content);
            if (tokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                SearchResponse = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                return SearchResponse;
            }
```

and the method that sets the header:

```
 private HttpClient Method_Headers(string apiKey, string endpointURL)
    {
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler() { UseDefaultCredentials = false };
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(endpointURL);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("key", apiKey);
            //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + apiKey);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return client;
    }
```

When I run it I'm getting an error:

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, Content: }
```

What am I'm missing?

Avi

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57280237/is-there-an-gcloud-auth-application-default-print-access-token-equivalent-in-c This maybe helpful.